# SQL Pivot Table Multiple Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Title01    Title02     Title03       Title04        Title05
Number     Title       Division      Department     IFC
```

And I am wanting to turn the columns into rows so it loos like this:

```
Field
Number
Title
Division
Department
IFC
```

Is it possible to do this using the PIVOT function in SQL?

Comment: There are countless examples of Pivot both dynamic and static.  However, the inital concern is how to enforce the proper sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use `CROSS APPLY` for this:

```
select v.field
from t cross apply
     (values (title01), (title02), (title03), (title04), (title05)
     ) v(field);
```

`CROSS APPLY` implements the lateral join.  You can think of it as an extension of correlated subqueries -- but the subquery can return multiple columns and multiple rows.  Unpivoting data happens to be a simple introduction to the concept.

Comment: Didn't even know about Cross Apply, this is much simpler than using Pivot, thank you!